# draw ascii square spiral c++ with a filling in it (Output on terminal itself)

Tags: c++, terminal, drawing, ascii

I have been desperately looking for a definite answer for this. The challenge was beyond my thinking scope or wasn't enough.

There was something topic like Spiral, but mostly is about matrix. If it is about the ascii art, nothing answer look's like this problem I have.

Suppose you have an integer N

```
int N;
```

Now, I input the N with an integer value

```
scanf("%d", N); fflush(stdin);
```

Let's see some examples:

- 1

  ```
  #
  ```
- 5

  ```
  #####
  ....#
  ###.#
  #...#
  #####
  ```
- 9

  ```
  #########
  ........#
  #######.#
  #.....#.#
  #.###.#.#
  #.#...#.#
  #.#####.#
  #.......#
  #########
  ```
- 11

  ```
  ###########
  ..........#
  #########.#
  #.......#.#
  #.#####.#.#
  #.#...#.#.#
  #.#.###.#.#
  #.#.....#.#
  #.#######.#
  #.........#
  ###########
  ```
- and so on.

I have a difficulty to understand and write the algorithm for it.
I had tried to search for help but none of them fit my expectation.
Here are some of the last attempts

- Attempt A

  ```
  #include<stdio.h>
  #include<iostream>
  #include<math.h>
  #include<string.h>
  #include<ctype.h>
  #include<stdlib.h>

  using namespace std;

  void Spirality(int N, char Border, char Fill) {

  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
          printf("%c", Border);
          for (int k = 0; k < j; k++) {
              printf("%c", Fill);
          }
      };
      printf("\n");
  };
  };

  int main() {
      int N;
      char Out = '#', In = '.';
      char A[101][101];


  scanf("%d", &N); fflush(stdin);

  int len = N, k = 1, p = 0, i;

  Spirality(N, Out, In);
  printf("\n");

  getchar();
  return 0;
  }
  ```

  Result: N is 5

  ```
  5

  #
  ##.
  ##.#..
  ##.#..#...
  ```
- Attempt B

  ```
  #include<stdio.h>
  #include<iostream>
  #include<math.h>
  #include<string.h>
  #include<ctype.h>
  #include<stdlib.h>

  using namespace std;

  void Spirality(int N, char Border, char Fill) {
      for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
          for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) printf("%c", Border);
          printf("\n");
          for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) printf("%c", Fill);
      };
  };

  int main() {
      int N;
      char Out = '#', In = '.';
      char A[101][101];


  scanf("%d", &N); fflush(stdin);

  Spirality(N, Out, In);
  printf("\n");

  getchar();
  return 0;
  }
  ```

  Result: N is 5

  ```
  #####
  .....#####
  .....#####
  .....#####
  .....#####
  .....
  ```

None of these output expected spiral.

Comment: What are the results of your attempts?

Comment: @Loren Ok, I will edit. hold on...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to draw a spiral of # with only for/while loops and if/else statements (without arrays) using C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51691446/how-to-draw-a-spiral-of-with-only-for-while-loops-and-if-else-statements-with)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, let's take a look at what your program has to output (line by line).

When N = 11, the output should be like (next to the "image" I will write configuration of your signs):

```
########### 11
..........# 10 1
#########.# 9 1 1
#.......#.# 1 7 1 1 1
#.#####.#.# 1 1 5 1 1 1 1
#.#...#.#.# 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 1
#.#.###.#.# 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 1
#.#.....#.# 1 1 1 5 1 1 1
#.#######.# 1 1 7 1 1
#.........# 1 9 1
########### 11
```

The line 1 7 1 1 1 means that at first one sign (#) has to be written, then 7 signs (.), and then 3x one sign (.#.).

Because all of our lines starts and ends with ones, and there is only one number, different from one in each line, we can simplify our problem (output) like this:

```
11
10 1
9 2
1 7 3
2 5 4
3 3 5
4 3 4
3 5 3
2 7 2
1 9 1
11
```

Note that in each line, except 2nd one, the first character is '#'.

So the function for the one line of output can look like that:

```
const char sign[2] = { '#', '.' };

void outputline(int l, int m, int r, int currsign) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        cout << sign[currsign] << ' ';
        currsign = (currsign + 1) % 2;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) cout << sign[currsign] << ' ';

    currsign = (currsign + 1) % 2;

    for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        cout << sign[currsign]<<' ';
        currsign = (currsign + 1) % 2;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

In the function, the first argument tells us, with how many ones line begins, m is the only number in the line that is not 1, r tells us with how many ones line ends and currsign is the index of the character that the line begins with.

Now the problem is reduced on how 3 numbers changes from line to line. If I copy paste it from above:

```
    l m r
    0 11 0
    0 10 1
    0 9 2
    1 7 3
    2 5 4
    3 3 5
    4 3 4
    3 5 3
    2 7 2
    1 9 1
    0 11 0
```

We can see, that the first 2 lines are a bit special (and therefore can be written separately). But for all other lines we can see simple rule.
Until m is not 3, it decreases for 2 in every steps, while l and r increase for 1. 
In the next step, m is 3 again, while l increases for 1 and r decreases for 1
And after that, until m is not N (11 in our case), m increases for 2 in every step, while l and r decrease for 1.
This algorithm works for every odd number.

You can do the same thing to see what are the patterns for each N(length of the side) divisible by 4 and for each N of the form 4*k+2.

So the main function should look like:

```
int main() {
    int N, n;
    cin >> N;

    int left = 0, middle = N, right = 2;

    if (N % 4 == 0) n = 4;
    else n = 2;

    outputline(0, middle--, 0, 0);
    if (middle == 0) return 0;
    outputline(0, middle--, 1, 1);
    if (middle == 0) return 0;

    for(middle; middle >=n; middle -=2)
        outputline(left++, middle, right++, 0);

    if (N % 2 == 1) {
        middle += 2;    right -= 2;
    }
    else if (N % 4 == 2) {
        left--; middle += 4; right-=3;
    }
    else if (N % 4 == 0) {
        left++; right--;
    }

    for (middle; middle <= N; middle += 2)
        outputline(left--, middle, right--, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Hope that the answer helps you.

Comment: this still has a problem when N is 1, prints 3 line of '#'s

Comment: Yeah, you can handle this case separately. Just add  
    if (middle == 1) {
  cout << sign[0] << endl;
  return 0;
    }
before the first outputline function call.

Or check if N is 1 after cin.

Comment: The code may probably be rewritten better, to include this case too. 
Can I ask you, for which numbers should it work (the code should work fine for N>5, but I don't really know what pattern do you need for N=3).

Comment: Anything N bellow about 3, cause problem. e.g. on N is 1 supposedly prints just a '#' after pres enter. N is 2, prints I think, '##' in a line, then '.#' in aline.

Comment: Yeah, I am asking what should be printed for N = 3 (and also for N=2, N=4)?

I will edit the code for N =1, but I really can't imagine how the spiral should look when N=2 ?

Comment: N is 1, just a '#'. N is 2, '##' endl then '.#'. N is 3, Mirrored C shapped formation of '#' with '.' formation at the rest of the gap (default operations as yours above).

Comment: Ok, now I think it should work. Please try, and comment:) Tommorow I will rewrite it, to be a little bit more compact, but today I really don't have time.